# Binary version 11.1.0 does not match the expected package version 9.7.0

Tags: reactjs, cypress

in my react repo

```
export CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=~/cypress-11.1.0.zip
yarn add -D cypress@11.1.0
```

later I found that does not support cypress.json

so I did

```
export CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=~/cypress-9.7.0.zip
yarn add -D cypress@9.7.0
```

Now it keeps complaining:

Binary version 11.1.0 does not match the expected package version 9.7.0

Update 1:
In my react repo, ./node_modules/.bin/cypress --version

```
Cypress package version: 9.7.0
Cypress binary version: 11.1.0 (???????)
Electron version: 21.0.0
Bundled Node version: 16.16.0
```

Answer (score 1):

`yarn add -D cypress@9.7.0` maybe is not doing a download to cache, due to the later version already present.

I always `yarn remove cypress` before installing another version.

Comment: Hi, ./node_modules/.bin/cypress --version -> Cypress binary version: 11.1.0. Is it a way to set it?

Comment: No it won't, nor should you attempt to patch things. Instead, remove the previous version and add the older version you desire.

Comment: Do you know where I can find "Cypress binary version: 11.1.0" It is not in the local repo and it is not in global @TesterDick

Comment: I just install it same way you have above. There's a newer version than that now.

Comment: You don't want a "retro" version anyway, stick with the up-to-date.